# Using BeautifulSoup and Pandas together

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse an HTML table and move data from there into my Oracle table. I can successfully capture the data from the HTML table, but the problem I can't seem to overcome is that when I put it into a Dictionary the data is no longer delimited at all. This causes an obvious problem when trying to export because values won't be exported correctly.

Also, I have 100's of other data tables that are identical in format but with different values inside that also need to be parsed, so this code needs to be robust enough to work on all of them.

AND, in each of these data tables I need ONLY the most recent date's corresponding data. This will make more sense when looking at the table below.

I'm not sure if the method I'm using for this project is the best one so all advice is gladly accepted. Thanks.

[image: My data table. Note I only need the data corresponding to 5/20 since that is the most recent date.]

My relevant code:

```
tabulka = soup.find("table", {"class" : "MsoNormalTable"})

column_headers = ['ID', 'Available Quota', 'Live Weight Pounds', 'Price', 'Date Posted']
records = []
for idy, row in enumerate(tabulka.findAll('tr')):
    if idy == 0:
        continue
    cols = row.findAll('td')
    record = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cols):
        record[column_headers[idx]] = col.text.strip()
    records.append(record)

print(records)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(records)

latest_date = df['Date Posted'].iloc[0]
latest_rows = df[df['Date Posted'] == latest_date]

print(latest_rows)
```

What `print(records)` prints:

```
[{'Live Weight Pounds': '2328445300785031011995', 'Available Quota': 'GOM CODGOM HADDGOM BBGREYSOLEDABSGOM YT', 'ID': '1724', 'Price': 'Package\xa0$9,000', 'Date Posted': '5/20'}, {'Live Weight Pounds': '5385894175524349015339652727922715060', 'Available Quota': 'GBE CODGBW CODGB BBGB YTSNE BBSNE YTGOM BBWhakePOLLRED', 'ID': '1578', 'Price': '$1.00$0.40$0.20$1.00$0.45$0.50$0.15$0.20$0.01$0.01', 'Date Posted': '5/20'}, {'Live Weight Pounds': '82590331241312065234766101688119521217285', 'Available Quota': 'GBE CODGBW CODDABSWHAKEPOLLREDSNE BBGOM BB', 'ID': '310', 'Price': 'Package\xa0$15,000', 'Date Posted': '5/20'}, {'Live Weight Pounds': '8,000', 'Available Quota': 'SNE BB', 'ID': '347', 'Price': '$0.50', 'Date Posted': '5/7'}, {'Live Weight Pounds': '618863539167873676233589776271186550', 'Available Quota': 'GOM CODGOM HADDSNE BBGOM BBGB BBGREYSOLEGOM YTSNE YTPOLL', 'ID': '1878A', 'Price': '$1.95$1.35$0.50$0.50$0.20$1.40$1.20$0.50$0.01', 'Date Posted': '5/12'}, {'Live Weight Pounds': '111312186850', 'Available Quota': 'GBE CODGBW CODGB YT', 'ID': '1878B', 'Price': 'Package$10,000', 'Date Posted': '5/12'}]
```

What `print(latest_rows)` prints:

```
                                     Available Quota Date Posted    ID  \
0            GOM CODGOM HADDGOM BBGREYSOLEDABSGOM YT        5/20  1724   
1  GBE CODGBW CODGB BBGB YTSNE BBSNE YTGOM BBWhak...        5/20  1578   
2         GBE CODGBW CODDABSWHAKEPOLLREDSNE BBGOM BB        5/20   310   

                          Live Weight Pounds  \
0                     2328445300785031011995   
1      5385894175524349015339652727922715060   
2  82590331241312065234766101688119521217285   

                                               Price  
0                                     Package $9,000  
1  $1.00$0.40$0.20$1.00$0.45$0.50$0.15$0.20$0.01$...  
2                                    Package $15,000
```

So I'm very close to succeeding but everything is delimited incorrectly. I'm hoping this is a simple fix that I'm just not aware of as a beginner. Thanks for any help.

And also here's the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>FW: NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21</title>
<link rel="important stylesheet" href="">
<style>div.headerdisplayname {font-weight:bold;}</style></head>
<body>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part1"><tr><td><b>Subject: </b>FW: NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21</td></tr><tr><td><b>From: </b>Claire Fitz-Gerald <claire@capecodfishermen.org></td></tr><tr><td><b>Date: </b>5/21/2014 10:08 AM</td></tr></table><br>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; "><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered medium)"><!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book";
    panose-1:2 11 5 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi";
    panose-1:2 11 7 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:windowtext;}
span.title1
    {mso-style-name:title1;
    font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
    color:#1F487E;
    font-weight:normal;}
span.EmailStyle19
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Please see the below quota listings.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Thanks,<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Claire Fitz-Gerald<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi","sans-serif";color:#002776'>Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance<o:p></o:p></span></b></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'>~ Small Boats.&nbsp; Big Ideas. ~</span></b><b><span style='color:#DE3500'><o:p></o:p></span></b></p></div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><div style='border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>From:</span></b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> David Leveille [mailto:nefs02@gmail.com] <br><b>Sent:</b> Wednesday, May 21, 2014 8:50 AM<br><b>To:</b> David Leveille<br><b>Subject:</b> NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21<o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:#1F487E'>AVAILABLE QUOTA FY 2014</span><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'><o:p></o:p></span></p><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="71%" style='width:71.28%'><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>ID <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Available Quota <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Live Weight Pounds <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Price <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Date Posted <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1724<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>GOM BB<br>GREYSOLE<br>DABS<br>GOM YT<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>2328<br>445<br>3007<br>850<br>3101<br>1995<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Package<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$9,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1578<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>GB BB<br>GB YT<br>SNE BB<br>SNE YT<br>GOM BB<br>Whake<br>POLL<br>RED<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>538<br>5894<br>1755<br>243<br>490<br>153<br>3965<br>2727<br>9227<br>15060<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.00<br>$0.40<br>$0.20<br>$1.00<br>$0.45<br>$0.50<br>$0.15<br>$0.20<br>$0.01<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>310<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>DABS<br>WHAKE<br>POLL<br>RED<br>SNE BB<br>GOM BB<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>825<br>9033<br>1241<br>3120<br>65234<br>76610<br>1688<br>1195<br>2121<br>7285<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Package<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$15,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr style='height:23.25pt'><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>347<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>SNE BB<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>8,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$0.50<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/7<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1878A<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>SNE BB<br>GOM BB<br>GB BB<br>GREYSOLE<br>GOM YT<br>SNE YT<br>POLL<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>6188<br>635<br>3916<br>7873<br>6762<br>3358<br>9776<br>271<br>186550<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.95<br>$1.35<br>$0.50<br>$0.50<br>$0.20<br>$1.40<br>$1.20<br>$0.50<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/12<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1878B<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>GB YT<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1113<br>12186<br>850<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Package<br>$10,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/12<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr></table><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>David Leveille<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>II Northeast Fishery Sector Inc.<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>10 Witham Street<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Gloucester, MA. 01930<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Cell 978 375 3509<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Fax 978 281 1555<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Web <a href="http://nefs2.com/">http://nefs2.com/</a><o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><div class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'></body></html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide a link to the page you want to parse?

Comment: The data table is in an email, as are all the tables. But I can add in the HTML code, sorry I forgot that

Comment: The problem seems to be that the text in your cell has newlines. You'll have to split it by `\n` and make one entry per result. It is not trivial, but doable.

Comment: @theprowler, can you post your desired data set?

Comment: @MaxU ideally I want all the data corresponding to the date 5/20, for this example, to be cleanly parsed and exported to my Oracle table. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [168]: %paste
def read_html_latest(filename, **kwargs):
    with open(filename) as f:
        text = f.read().replace('<br>', ' ')
    df = pd.read_html(text, **kwargs)[0]
    # fix column names
    df.columns = df.loc[0]
    df = df.loc[1:]
    return df.assign(d=pd.to_datetime(df['Date Posted'], format='%m/%d')) \
             .query('d == d.max()') \
             .drop('d', 1)
## -- End pasted text --

In [169]: df = read_html_latest(filename, attrs={'class': 'MsoNormalTable'})

In [170]: df
Out[170]:
0    ID                                    Available Quota  \
1  1724       GOM COD GOM HADD GOM BB GREYSOLE DABS GOM YT
2  1578  GBE COD GBW COD GB BB GB YT SNE BB SNE YT GOM ...
3   310  GBE COD GBW COD DABS WHAKE POLL RED SNE BB GOM BB

0                                 Live Weight Pounds  \
1                        2328 445 3007 850 3101 1995
2     538 5894 1755 243 490 153 3965 2727 9227 15060
3  825 9033 1241 3120 65234 76610 1688 1195 2121 ...

0                                              Price Date Posted
1                                     Package $9,000        5/20
2  $1.00 $0.40 $0.20 $1.00 $0.45 $0.50 $0.15 $0.2...        5/20
3                                    Package $15,000        5/20
```

Comment: I received the error `ValueError: No text parsed from document: <_io.TextIOWrapper` which confuses me? Tell me if I did this wrong though; here's what I did: `path = 'Z:\\blub'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            df = pd.read_html(f, attrs={'class': 'MsoNormalTable'})[0]
            column_headers = ['ID', 'Available Quota', 'Live Weight Pounds', 'Price', 'Date Posted']
            df.columns = df.loc[0]
            df = df.loc[1:]

            print(df)`

Comment: Wow sorry that looks so messy, I can't start text on new lines in comments.

Comment: @theprowler, try this instead: `df = pd.read_html(file_path , attrs={'class': 'MsoNormalTable'})[0]`

Comment: So that has successfully captured the data, all of it btw not just the 5/20 data, but the Available Quota and the Live Weight Pounds values are still not delimited at all.......is that what you were talking about with the newline `\n` stuff?

Comment: WOW. It worked! Now all that's left to do is export it, and now that it's a cleaner printout the export should be quick and easy. Thanks a ton man

Comment: God this is frustrating. So the export didn't work. But now that I think of it I don't think that's your fault/Pandas fault. I have a question though: do you know if when trying to export that printout of data to an Oracle table via sqldeveloper, will it all align correctly as in the original data table? Because the error I receive when trying to put the data directly into my Oracle table is `value too large for column (actual: 59, max: 50)`. So I think what's happening is all of those prices are trying to go into one cell rather than all the cells. But I might be wrong..

Comment: @theprowler, `Package $9,000` - this is one cell and `538 5894 1755 243 490 153 3965 2727 9227 15060` - is also one cell

Comment: Ohhh gotcha. Do you know of a way to make `1724` `GOM COD` `2328` `Package $9,000` and `5/20` for example all be in their own cells and in the same row? Because that's my current dilemma, situating all the data correctly

Comment: @theprowler, i would suggest you to open a new question asking how to convert your HTML table into something that you want to have in Oracle DB at the end. In your current HTML table - how would you parse a row where (`ID == 310`) as you have 8 values in `Available Quota` and 10 values in the `Live Weight Pounds` column? How do you want to match them? Basically you would need to specify a shorter version of your HTML tables (for example take only 2 rows) and specify ypur desired output data set.